# Amazon SES: To send mail to large number of users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I want to send mail to large number of users, I did some research about it and found that we can send mail to maximum 50 recipients at one API call.

But I have more than 500 users, and need to send mail to all of them.

I have tried with AWS lambda + SES and mail sending is working, but all  recipients are showing in to mail:
["**@**","**@**","**@**",...]
How could I hide other recipients?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information, all I can do is provide an answer that represents general architectural guidance.

I would architect your Lambdas in such a way that minimizes the amount of "work" that each Lambda does. In this case, you should have a Lambda that handles your business logic necessary to construct a message, and another Lambda that handles sending email, either in batches or as one-off messages, in addition to handling rate limiting, batch size, etc.

From your "business logic" Lambda, call the "email sending" Lambda as many times as you need. The platform will handle provisioning the necessary execution environments.

Serverless really allows you to have functions that follow the [Unix Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) - do one thing and do it well.